# dos formularios no me actualiza , ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

tengo un problema tengo dos formularios en el primero se guarda unos campos y despues en el segundo se guarda otros cuando voy a actualizar el id me sale un error.

el segundo formulario el campo es :atencion .
 gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
     def update
       respond_to do |format|
        if @reunion.update(reunion_params)
             format.html { redirect_to @reunion, notice: 'Reunion was successfully updated.' }
             format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @reunion }
        else
          @negocios = Negocio.all
             format.html { render :edit }
             format.json { render json: @reunion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end

     end
   end


    private

   def set_reunion
       @reunion = Reunion.find(params[:id])
   end



   def reunion_params
     params.require(:reunion).permit( :observacion, :subtotal,
     :planta_id, :ubicacion,:hora_entre,:nombre,:atencion,
     :producto_id,:cantidad,:valor,:reunionvalor_id)
   end
```

reunion.erb

modelo

```
  class Reunion < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'reuniones'
  belongs_to :planta
  belongs_to :centro_costo
  belongs_to :producto

  self.table_name = 'reuniones' 


  before_validation :asignar_valores_por_defecto_reunion


   def asignar_valores_por_defecto_reunion
    Time.zone = "America/Bogota"
    self.hora_pedido = Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S" )
  end


  #Autocomplete

   def centro_costo_fullname
     centro_costo.fullname if centro_costo
   end

   def centro_costo_fullname=(fullname)
      self.centro_costo = CentroCosto.find_by_fullname(fullname) unless fullname.blank?
   end

   before_save :guardarreunion


   def guardarreunion
    self.reunionfullnombre  =self.nombre+" "+self.fecha_pedido.to_s+" "+self.fecha_entrega.to_s+" "+
self.ubicacion+" "+CentroCosto.where("id=?",self.centro_costo).last.fullname+" "+Planta.where("id=?",self.planta).last.plantafullnombre
   end


 # validaciones

   validates_presence_of :centro_costo_fullname
   validates  :ubicacion, presence: true, length: {minimum: 4, maximum: 50}
   validates  :nombre, presence: true, length: {minimum: 4, maximum: 50} 

   #El metodo que asigna los valores
    validate :asignar_valores_por_defecto_reunion
    def asignar_valores_por_defecto_reunion
      Time.zone = "America/Bogota"
      self.fecha_pedido = Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
      self.hora_pedido = Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S" )
    end

validate :validar_horas  
#valida las horas. 
def validar_horas
  #Hora medotodo  cual es mayor  que otro
   if  hora_inicio < hora_final

   else
    errors.add(:hora_final,"La hora final de la reunion debe
    ser mayor a la de hora inicial")
   end
   #Condicion que tiene que ser mayor  a 4 horas

    if ( hora_final - ( 60 * 60 * 4 ) ) <= ( hora_inicio )

       validates_presence_of :observacion ,:message => 'La hora final debe ser mayor a 4 hora,
      Explicar por que No cumple 
      las politicas del Negocio, y el campo sera deshabilitado,'


    end


 end  

 #validate :prueba

 def prueba
  self.hora_pedido = Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S" )
  if ( fecha_entrega - ( 60 * 60 * 24 ) ) <= ( hora_pedido )

   validates_presence_of :observacion ,:message => 'error 24,  '
  end
 end

validate :fecha_permitida
def fecha_permitida
  if self.fecha_entrega
    Time.zone = "America/Bogota"
    if self.fecha_entrega < Time.zone.now
      p self.fecha_entrega
     errors.add(:fecha_entrega, "Fecha y hora de entrega
    No puede ser de diás,hora o minutos anteriores de la hora actual")
    end
  end
end
```

end

Comment: Debe haber alguna validación en el modelo que no deja actualizar. Agrega eso a la pregunta

Comment: @alter-lago  como  hago para que  me la deje pasar solo  a ese campo?
 gracias

Comment: Por eso te digo, que agregues el código del modelo. Con la información que estás entregando no es suficiente para ayudarte

Comment: @AlterLagos si es de validate es la que impide la actualización, como seria para que pasara la validación? al actualizar el revisa todos los campo por eso me arroja el error. gracias

Comment: En tu controlador después de llamar a `@reunion.update`, prueba a ver que te muestra `@reunion.errors.full_messages` en el else y verás cual validación te está fallando

Comment: @AlterLagos hola  este es el error validate :validar_horas , es la valiacion que esta en el modelo si me puedes decir como la puedo mejorar para que no me de error seria bueno gracias